# restore snapshots from another instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, database-restore

I have 2 amazon rds instance (one for production, and another for development/testing). Now I want to restore one database from production instance to my development instance. I am taking snapshots on my production instance, but there is no options to restore snapshots on development instance from another instance.

Is there any way to do this without downloading snapshot?

Answer (score 4):

Restoring from snapshot means creating a new RDS instance, so you will basically be replacing the old development instance with a new one.

First you have to either delete or rename the original development instance, otherwise it's name can't be reused for the new instance.

If you want an RDS instance with both the development schema and production schema, then you'll have to transfer the data using database-specific tools (e.g., mysqldump if you're using MySQL, data pump if using Oracle, etc).

Comment: thanks for replying. I am already using mysqldump to restore database on my development instance. But it is very time taking job, and also read block occurred while taking backup from production instance (It is very bed situation).

Comment: @ManishSapkal what this answer is telling you is, you need to restore the snapshot onto a *new* instance, and then either delete the *old* dev instance and start using this new one for dev, or, use `mysqldump` to transfer data from the new instance to the old dev instance (then you can delete the new instance created by the restore action)... either way, you'd leave production alone.  Also, adding `--single-transaction` to `mysqldump` should prevent lockups if you're using InnoDB.

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot, I am ready to use new dev instance. but How Do I restore snapshot of my production instance? Is there any option to chose snapshots of other instance?

Comment: You don't.  Restoring a snapshot *always* creates  *new* instance.  It doesn't modify  existing one.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the attributes on the (production) snapshot and allow another AWS account (Dev, in your case) to access it

```
aws rds modify-db-snapshot-attribute --db-snapshot-identifier $SNAPSHOT_NAME --attribute-name restore --values-to-add "<ACCOUNT NUMBER FOR DEV>" --output=json
```

Attribute name = Restore, because you are having dev account restore from this snapshot.

in your dev console, you will find this on the "Shared snapshots"

Answer (score 0):

Starting Late 2015, the sharing of snapshot has been added as a feature by AWS.

[Sharing Snapshot across AWS Accounts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-update-cross-account-snapshot-sharing/)

Comment: could you please bring the necessary portion here?

Comment: @manetsus: I would love to, but I'm not sure if AWS would sue me for doing that.

Comment: You should give the proper attribution. would not it be well enough?